# problem booting from 3.0 USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, windows-10

I have a Dell xps 13 9370  with only 3.0 USB ports. I'm trying to install Ubuntu (Windows 10 is now installed), I followed all the steps indicated here https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0 .

The problem is that when I restart the pc and press f12 to boot from usb I cannot find such option, just the ordinary windows boot option.. I read that there might be problems with 3.0 usb ports, do you think this might be the case? I'm plugged in with a 2.0 usb through a 2.0 to 3.0 adaptor, does this effectively count as a 2.0 or a 3.0?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that the USB 2.0 stick is the source of the problem. It seems like some kind of bios configuration problem. The following steps may help:

1. Tap F12 continuously to enter bios configuration.
2. Go to Settings -> Boot sequence. If your USB drive appears there, make it be the 1st in the list. Save and reboot.
3. If it does not appear, go to System configuration -> USB Configuration. Select "Enable boot support" and "Enable external USB port" (if they are not selected). Save and reboot to bios configuration. Now under Settings -> Boot sequence you must see your USB. Goto 2.
4. If 3 did not work, check if your USB was properly prepared. Also, check that you downloaded a 64-bit version of the OS.

If after booting from your live USB, Ubuntu does not recognize your SSD, and your SSD is M.2 PCIe, reboot again to bios and go to System Configuration -> SATA Operation. If "RAID On" is selected, select "AHCI". Before doing this I recommend you to prepare a separate windows restoration USB.

See also https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-10/Dell-Inspiron-15-7567-won-t-boot-from-USB/m-p/5162753#M9759